# How do I fix these buttons (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, button, github-pages

I want to align my button to the left, increase the article container, and have a hover transition. I just don't know how to achieve this. See [here](https://github.com/drippy-cat/drippy-cat.github.io/edit/main/index.html) for the full code (cannot post all because it was flagged as spam).

This is the code I have so far:

```
            <div class="button-container">
                <a href="https://www.holopin.io/@drippycat" class="button primary">Holopin</a>
            </div>
        <style>
        .button-container {
        display: flex;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        cursor: pointer;
     }

     .button-container a.button {
       margin-right: 15px;
 }
        </style>
                                
    </article>
```

I want to move the Holopin button to the left and resize the article container to fit all the buttons (see attached image). I also wish to modify the buttons so that they have a similar animation to Button: Slide Right (as seen [here](https://codepen.io/RazorXio/pen/gMaoOW)).

Comment: Why link your entire project?  Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you using Bootstrap?